# Sass .scss: Nesting extra class on div

Tags: css, sass

I'm trying to display a `div` with a simple `display:none/block`. When a button is clicked, I append an `.active` class to my `div`.

I wan't to target this `.active` class using SASS, but I can't do it if I try to nest it.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="MyDiv">
   I'm a hidden div. But when some button is clicked I get the class Active
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".MyDiv").on("click", function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

**CSS:** (What I expect after SASS compiles)

```
.MyDiv {
   display:none;
 }

.MyDiv.active {
   display:block; 
 }
```

**SASS**

```
.MyDiv {
  display:none;

  .active {
    display:block; /* this one doesn't work */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write the way you are writing, it compiles to `.MyDiv .active` which is not what you want, you need to use `&.active` so your selector will be `.MyDiv.active`

```
.MyDiv {
  display: none;

  &.active {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the Sass properly. If you want to have another sibling class for MyDiv you need to use &.active in Sass. [Link to Css-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/the-sass-ampersand/#article-header-id-1)

```
.MyDiv {
  display:none;
  &.active {
    display:block;
  }
}
```

It compiles to

```
.MyDiv.active {
  display: block;
}
```

Your code compiles to. You see the space between .MyDiv and .active

```
.MyDiv .active {
  display: block;
}
```